# Chrome Session lost for corrupted preference file

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

I restarted my computer while it stopped responding after a hibernation.

Now when I re opened Chrome again, is says my preference file has corrupted. And I dont have the session restore button anymore.

What can I do to have that session or the informations about that sessions back.

I am assuming that, it's just the preferenece file, that hold the info "reopen last opened tab on chrome starts" that is corrupted. My session storing files are still intact.

So, how should I proceed to get them back?

( I havn't done anything with chrome after that, it is opned with a new tab.)

Comment: you still need help with this?

Comment: Would be great if I get a solution.

Comment: Some insight of this answer can be found on this question : [Chrome crashed without providing “Restore” button](http://superuser.com/questions/342437/chrome-crashed-without-providing-restore-button)